# How to delete file created in with statement if with-block fails (python)

Tags: python, with-statement, resource-cleanup

I have some code like this:

```
with open(output_path, 'w') as output_file:
    #create and write output file
```

Upon running this, then even if there is an error somewhere, the file has been created and is in an incomplete state .

I would like it, that if there is an exception raised (and not handled) in the with-block, then the file be deleted. What's the best way to do this?

My understanding is if I try to do it in with a (try ...) `finally` statement, it will happen even if there is no exception, while if I put it after an `except` statement, the exception will not continue to bubble up, which is what I want it to do. (I don't want to handle the exception, just delete the file before the code stops running.)

Comment: Why would you not catch the exception?

Comment: incomplete state ? :O

Comment: @IanAuld I wanted the exception to continue to bubble up. It could be anything, even a KeyboardInterrupt. I just wanted the file to be deleted if it wasn't complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call raise within your except block, and it will re-raise the exception to allow the exception to bubble up. [See this relevant section of python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions).

For your example, you could write something similar to the following:

```
try:
    with open(output_path, 'w') as output_file:
        # Create and write output file.
except:
    # Delete the file.
    # Re-raise the exception with all relevant information (message, stacktrace, etc).
    raise
```